# How to make angular app really modular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

1. How to avoid of declaration all scripts together in index.html? How to load scripts only if they're necessary?
   Should I use RequireJs to solve this problem?
2. Same problem with angular.module dependencies. How to load them only when they are used in controller?

How to make angular app really modular not only with files structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use requirejs to load script when necessary
Refer http://startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs

Comment: Thanks a lot! It might help

Answer (score 0):

If you have some dependencies in your app,you have to load all javascript files of your dependencies.RequireJs will not help you,to solve it.You will have the error anyway.

Comment: Wow...thanks for warning.
I have an idea to make many modules and inject them in each other if necessary